# Can I detach a rust thread?

Tags: rust

The spawn below

```
fn something() {
    std::thread::spawn(||{
        println!("hello");
    });
}
```

creates a `JoinHandle` which is waited until it finishes. This blocks the return of `something`.

Is there a way to detach this thread in Rust? In this case my `JoinHandle` isn't `Send` so I can't keep it around. This is mostly for testing, I'd not leave a thread hanging alone somewhere in my program

Comment: That is incorrect. As per  the [documentation on `std::thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) : _"If the join handle is dropped, the spawned thread will implicitly be detached. In this case, the spawned thread may no longer be joined. (It is the responsibility of the program to either eventually join threads it creates or detach them; otherwise, a resource leak will result.)"_

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111143/how-can-you-wait-for-detached-threads-or-control-how-threads-are-spawned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`something` is only blocked if you join the thread. Dropping a `JoinHandle` doesn't join a thread; it detaches it.

[`spawn`'s documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) says (emphasis added):

> Spawns a new thread, returning a `JoinHandle` for it.
>
> The join handle provides a `join` method that can be used to join the spawned thread. If the spawned thread panics, `join` will return an `Err` containing the argument given to `panic!`.
>
> **If the join handle is dropped, the spawned thread will implicitly be *detached*. In this case, the spawned thread may no longer be joined.**